# Is the UTxO for change always the very last index of the outputs?

Tags: transaction, utxo

Given a transaction with multiple outputs, is the UTxO for the change always the very last index of the list of all outputs?

To demonstrate what I mean:

Given the following theoretical transaction

```
transaction
 - input #1 (100M lovelace from address XX0)
 - output idx#0 (40M lovelace to address XX1)
 - output idx#1 (50M lovelace to address XX2)
 - output idx#2 (10M lovelace change to address XX0)
```

Is it safe to assume the change is ALWAYS the last index of the output list?

It does make sense to me, but I need to know if I can rely on that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends what wallet/client you're using to build the transaction. The concept of "change" is at the application level. As far as the ledger is concerned, it doesn't exist at all. All that's important is that the transaction balances.

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense!